# Get a specific view controller from a xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

I don't like auto layout, so I just use the typical Xcode 5 storyboards. I have a View Controller in my xib for each screen size. How can I, programmatically, get the view controller  that is the right size and then present that?

Comment: So then don't use autolayout, lay things out programmatically. Creating a bunch of different view controllers for different screen sizes makes it sound like you're trying to give yourself a headache & introduce bugs on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use separate view controllers for different screen sizes.  You should use the same view controller, and load a different xib depending on the screen size.  You will probably have the same elements in the xibs for the different screen sizes so a single view controller should be able to handle any size.

Answer (score 1):

I used to hate Interface Builder and Autoresizing mask. I had placed subviews programatically. But I changed my mind since I understood Auto Layout. Almost all of layout things will be very easy if you understand Auto Layout. I know some situations need to write codes. You can use xib to make custom view for complicated layout. And also you can make custom views fully programmatically.

Xib file does not support Layout Guide. My solution is to make storyboard for each ViewController. Layout Guide things messed you up if you try to layout programmatically.